# How to Count Unique Values From a Repeated List in Priority with a Cell - Google Spreadsheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with four columns:

```
question_id  user_id   unique_question_ids   # of unique_user_ids
X            11        X                     ? (=2)
X            12        Y                     ? (=3)
X            12
X            12
Y            13
Y            14
Y            15
```

The first two columns are questions and their corresponding users and include repeats of both.

**The objective is this:  I want to count the number of unique users for each unique question.**

I started with first finding the unique_questions which I found using the UNIQUE function. This listed what questions are unique in the unique_question_ids column (i.e. X, Y)

Now I want to count the number of unique users that each unique question has?  The other problem is that I do not know where X and Y start, however they are still sorted in order (real spreadsheet is very large).

How would I go about doing this?  I am thinking I could use COUNTIFS but this doesn't count for unique values.  I also thinking of using a function that would return the range of where X or Y is located in the question_id column, and then count in the next column (i.e. user_id) for unique values.  But I cannot find a function that returns the cell range of a value in a column.  I am also doing this on Google Spreadsheets.

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data starts at cell A1, you can use this formula in cell C1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(UNIQUE(A2:B8),"SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 LABEL Col1 'unique_question', COUNT(Col2) 'unique_users'",-1))
```

It's basically an SQL query using the unique values from `unique(A2:B8)` and counting the values from the second column based on the first column values.

[Google Spreadsheet sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IlAeSzSpznvc3H613B-dJ2K8j0ezFMu_snXOndKWrYc/edit?usp=sharing)

---

Some explanation:

The Unique table data after passing through `UNIQUE()` is like this:

```
question_id  user_id
X            11 
X            12 
Y            13
Y            14
Y            15
```

The SQL language (specific to GoogleSpreadsheet) is like this:

```
SELECT                         -- From the data,
    Col1,                      -- select column 1 (unique question_id)
    COUNT(Col2)                -- select the count of column 2 (unique user_id)
GROUP BY
    Col1                       -- group by the first column *
LABEL
    Col1 'unique_question',    -- label the first column as 'unique_question'
    COUNT(Col2) 'unique_users' -- label the second column as 'unique_users'
```

- When you apply an aggregate function to a column, e.g. `COUNT()` is an aggregate function, you have to use `GROUP BY` on the other columns to decide what should happen to them.

For instance, if you use this on the above data:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(Col2)
```

You will end up with `5` (this is one row), because it is counting all the rows in the table data. If you try:

```
SELECT
    Col1,
    COUNT(Col2)
```

You will end up with 5 rows for Col1 and 1 row for the function result, which is not allowed. So, you need `GROUP BY` to tell that all similar values in Col1 should occupy one row, so that you have one row for `X` and one for `Y` and then, the count will adapt to this grouping by counting all the `X` separately from the `Y`.

Comment: Hi Jerry, thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate it. I have never used query language before, do you mind explaining how the function works and what the string "SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 LABEL Col1 'unique_question', COUNT(Col2) 'unique_users'",-1" means?

Comment: @user3527095 I added some explanation. Hopefully it's clearer :)

Comment: Hi Jerry, Thanks a lot for the help, and especially with providing a detailed explanation. I really appreciate what you do to help out people.